# Using ds_add and Macros with Airflow

Tags: airflow

I want to get the `execution date - 2 months` in format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

This is what I wrote:

```
EXEC_TIMESTAMP_2_MONTHS_AGO = "{{ macros.ds_add(execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M'), -60) }}"
```

However this doesn't work. It doesn't render.

What is the problem?

Edit:
This is the operator:

```
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders_and_upload_to_storage',
    mysql_conn_id='mysqlcon',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcpcon',
    provide_context=True,
    sql = 'import_orders.sql',
    params={'max_Orders_ID_2_months_ago': EXEC_TIMESTAMP_2_MONTHS_AGO, 'table_name' :  TABLE_NAME},
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name,
    dag=dag)
```

Error is:

```
mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=60)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') }}\n   ' at line 51")
```

Comment: You should try putting the `{{...` into the templated `import_orders.sql` - I assume it is templated based on your previous question

Comment: @Mendhak check my comment to dlamblin

Comment: We're saying to put it directly into the SQL file, only use `params` to pass the most basic values needed, whereas this calculation can happen in the `.sql` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC the params values don't get templated. So the string value is being passed in explicitly.

Your example operator is loading `import_orders.sql`. So presumably you're using some template macro in there to load the values in the params dict. Macros never get recursively expanded. So instead just put the template as suggested with execution date minus a 60 day interval and with the string formatting you want directly into the sql file where you had a params macro.

E.G. if your SQL file looked like:

```
SELECT * FROM {{ params.table_name }}
WHERE ID > {{ params.max_Orders_ID_2_months_ago }};
```

I'm suggesting you put in the (corrected) macro:

```
SELECT * FROM {{ params.table_name }}
WHERE ID > {{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=60)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M') }};
```

Because the `macros.ds_add(ds, -60)` first of all only works on `%Y-%m-%d` strings like `{{ ds }}` and only outputs strings in `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: Put how? When I do:  `params={'max_Orders_ID_2_months_ago': '' {{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=60)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') }} '' , 'table_name' :  BQ_TABLE_NAME},`
   it gives  `invalid syntax`

Comment: @Programmer120 This was a mobile authored reply, and the important opening statement got mangled. I fixed it. And yes, in your comment's code `''` is an empty string and doesn't concat with a dict `{…}`.
You should probably install apache-airflow in a venv and before putting your code into a running system `cd $DAGS_DIRECTORY; PYTHONPATH=. python -c 'from pprint import pprint; from path.to.dag_file import dag_variable; pprint(dag_variable);'`

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you should include any error messages from the log in your post, this will help with future searchers and also helps narrow down the problem.

I think what's happening now is you're using `ds_add` but on execution_date which is a proper datetime.  Normally it's done on `ds` which is a string representation.

Instead you will need to subtract directly from the execution_date and *then* format it the way you want.

```
{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=60)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M') }}
```

For completeness - that calculation can only happen in your templated sql or templated sql file.

Comment: This also doesn't work. This should be replaced to a timestamp which I use in the query of MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator . Error is: ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ (execution_date - macro       which actualy means that the value was not redered

Comment: Can you edit your post to include that error message and how you're calling it from the operator